# Type error: Tuple indices must be integers, not tuple

Tags: python

I am trying to get this method to work, but it won't.

Relevant code:

```
for (i, t) in enumerate(transitions[location]):
    print i+1, t[0]
actionChoice=int(raw_input("> "))
console.clear()
transitions=transitions[location][actionChoice-1]
```

I get the Type Error: tuple indices must be integers, not tuple

Where should I fix it? What does it mean?

Answer (score 5):

`location` is a tuple. This line causes the error: `transitions[location]`

Also note that `enumerate` accepts a `start` parameter so you can use `enumerate(x, start=1)` to avoid writing `i+1`

Comment: Explain like I'm five. I am new to python.

Comment: @location check the variable `location`, you are mistaking it for an integer but really it's a tuple, maybe you meant to use `location[0]` or something similar

Comment: Maybe it's meant to be `enumerate(transitions)`

Comment: I'm writing a text adventure. I can put the whole thing up but it is very strange. Is there a better way to do it than the method I am using?

Comment: @user2407771 that code does not give the error in your question. Also, it is generally preferred here that if you're showing more code, you edit it into the question rather than linking to pastebin.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a demo:

Correct:

```
>>> tup=(1,2)
>>> tup[0]
1
```

Not correct:

```
>>> tup[(0,0)]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: tuple indices must be integers, not tuple
>>> tup[1,]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: tuple indices must be integers, not tuple
```

Most probably, location is a tuple -- not an integer.